# emulate javascript onchange event on <div> and <span>

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I have the following from the Speech-To-Text Google demo

```
<div id="results">
<span id="final_span" class="final"> </span>
<span id="interim_span" class="interim"></span>
<p>
</div>
```

from [here](https://github.com/googlearchive/webplatform-samples/blob/master/webspeechdemo/webspeechdemo.html) I want to add the the input field with the text transcription an event that fires any time something is transcribed. Let say, a second field with the same trinscribed text. With onchange in an input field I would use:

```
<input type="text" onchange="alert(this.value)">
<input type="button" value="Button">
```

How can I achieve the same in the Google demo?

Comment: What have you tried and where that failed?

Comment: If you want to run some code whenever a `div` or `span` changes, then you may want to use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)